# Implementing Request Response design

Tags: java, design-patterns, functional-programming

I am trying to implement a request/response client. Here is the basic implementation for it.

```
Class Request
{
    prepareRequest1();
    prepareRequest2();
}

Class Response
{
    processResponse1();
    processResponse2();
}

Class Client
{
    connect();
    sendRequest();
}

myrequest = new Request();
client = new Client (myserver);
my $rawResponse1 = client.sendRequest (myrequest.prepareRequest1());

myresponse = new Response();
myresponse.processResponse1 ($rawResponse1);
```

I have three classes namely - Request, Response and Client. Request class contains a function specific to a request. These request are the XML requests. There XML request does not have anything in common except few initial tags (e.g. sessionid etc). All other XML parameters are specific to the type of request. So, Currently I am handing it by creating a separate function for each request. I understand that it has a scalability issue, but please suggest me some other best approach I can apply here.

Similar to the request, the response to each request require a specific treatment. so I have a separate function specific to each type of response I am expecting. Generally you can assume that there is a 1:1 mapping between request and response.

Last is the Client class which hands for connection.

I have almost 50+ such request and response, and I am planning to implement with this approach. As I am in initial stage of development, please suggest me some improvement/best practices to implement such request/response.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Its best if you keep the mapping of the request and response outside of your code. Easier to manage. Keep an xml config file that stores the class names of your request and response tied to a particular type of xml message. You can then obtain the class names and go to that class to process your request and response. Its best to have separate classes to handles these messages rather than separate methods. Thats more scalable. Ensure you have interface for all your request classes and the same for your response classes. This will make it easy to swap your request responses classes easily by modifying the xml config file..

Hope you got it :)

Comment: I have almost 50+ different type of messages (request/response). Is it good to have 50 classes, one for each message.

Comment: Having more classes is not a crime as long you find it easy to manage. But again that is my opinion. But if you dont want to manage these classes and have a 1-1 mapping between request and class, like I suggested, you can always try to club 'like' requests together and service them using the same class, but its best you keep this mapping of which xml request -> mapped to which class -> mapped to which method outside your code in an xml config file. That gives you the maximum flexibility. You will have instantiate your class and invoke the method via reflection

Comment: Thanks sethu, This looks more promising.